# Matlab precision when using norm

Tags: matlab, precision

The following Matlab command (MATLAB Version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b))

```
format long;
norm([9, 2])
```

gives

```
9.219544457292889
```

where as,

```
sqrt(9^2+2^2)
```

gives

```
9.219544457292887
```

Notice the last decimal place. Is this machine dependent? Why does this happen? How can I avoid it?

Comment: On my computer (Matlab R2010b) it gives the second result (ending in 7) in both cases. Maybe try `hypot(9,2)` also. Anyway, why do you want to avoid it? It's the usual numerical precision issue, and it's pretty good precision anyway

Comment: If you have the toolbox that supports `vpa`, you can use that for more precise results but in string format. `vpa(sqrt(9^2+2^2))` yields -  `9.2195444572928873100022742817628`. `vpa(norm([9, 2]))` yields the same i.e. `9.2195444572928873100022742817628`

Comment: `hypot(9,2)` gives me the second result. But I cannot use it as I want sum of squares for higher dimensions.

Comment: In Matlab 2014b I get the same result as you, just for the record

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to avoid it because otherwise when I perform non-dominated sorting, weakly-dominated points become strongly-dominated.

Comment: How about: Change your sorting in a way that considers everything equal that is closer than 1e-14?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good guide on how to [compare floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm). Because of several reasons (accumulation of errors, different algorithms, machine precision, etc), you might get slightly different answers when applying two different algorithms that in theory (done by hand) must return the same number (welcome to scientific computing!).

If one uses relative comparison betweeen the two results (Assuming the norm result is correct) you get:

```
abs(9.219544457292889 - 9.219544457292887) / 9.219544457292889 =  1.9267e-016
```

which is insignificant. For any practical purpose, you are getting exactly the same result.

If you want to obtain the exact answer, you must use an [Arbitrary-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library (as @Divakar mentions in the comment section), but you will pay the price of a much higher CPU usage.